# What's the better way to organize retrieval of difference in props

Tags: c#, code-quality

I have a system, which stores different objects in DB. Each such object has properties. Some of them are relevant for all objects (like Name, Description), but some are specific to each object and depend on its type.

Now I need to create a web method, that will retrieve that objects and their properties as set of POCOs.

Ideally, the response should be an array of such items:

```
public class ObjectInfo
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public Dictionary<string,string> Props {get;set;}
}
```

Before generating ObjectInfo collection - code goes to database and retrieves business objects. For instance, one object has type "text", another one - type "number". Number type has decimal property, which is not relevant for "text". Currently my code still puts into collection of props for text as well. But this is what I need to get change. And there is only such thing in my head - add if/else branches for each specific type - to indicate if it's needed to search for type specific property and add it to target props collection.

Is there a way better from SOLID and clean code perspective than if/else portion to add needed properties to Props dictionary based on type? So that they appear only for Objects where they are relevant. I thought about different creational patterns, but didn't find relevant.

```
        var resultItems = new List<ObjectInfo>();
        var businessObjects = this.GetBusinessObjects();
        foreach(var businessObject in businessObjects) 
        {
            var props = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            switch(businessObject.Type)
            {
                case "text":
                    props.Add("UsedInSearch", businessObject["UsedInSearch"]);
                    break;
                case "number":
                    props.Add("Decimal", businessObject["Decimal"]);
                    break;
                // number of cases will be potentially big. And number of props for each will also be different and bigger than one
            }

            var objectInfo = new ObjectInfo 
            {
                Name = businessObject["Name"],
                Props = props
            };
            resultItems.Add(objectInfo);
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Your code example doesn't include the code that adds properties to your ObjectInfo objects, so I don't know how we're supposed to meaningfully evaluate your design.

Comment: Can you also explain what you mean by "better," without resorting to wandering generalities like "best practice" "more elegant" or "most popular?"  Overall your question (and your objectives) needs to be more specific.

Comment: When writing code, I always try to keep in mind: SOLID and clean code. But cannot find good resolution here. I've extended the question a bit.

Comment: There isn't any way to tell from the code you've posted so far whether or not you're being SOLID and "clean."

Comment: `if`-`else` branches aren't necessarily dirty or bad or "unclean."  The [Factory Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) uses them to decide which class to instantiate.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#).

Comment: Thanks for the additional code.  Do you have a requirement that you need to be able to modify your `case` arrangement *outside of your case structure,* i.e. in a configuration file?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree. But I thought Factory method is kind of overhead here. Isn't it?

Comment: I didn't say "use a Factory Method."  I said "The Factory Method is an example of using `switch` in exactly the same manner as you are describing."

Comment: @RobertHarvey nope. No requirement related to outside of case. The code inside this swithc is something I'll need to define now and modify in the future. And the issue is that this code already has more than 1 reason for modification

Comment: What is the other reason?

Comment: One reason is the fact that specific type received one more property I need to handle. The second one - ObjectInfo can be extended with "ModifiedDate" property for example. 
Probably I'm treating that incorrectly and the reason is still one - return collection of ObjectInfo items...

Comment: Yes, it's still just one reason.

Comment: Could not "BusinessObject" just return the dictionary of properties it owns? BusinessObjects knows its type and its properties. The code above is ["asking" too much and not "telling" enough](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you only appear to have one "prop" per object type. Therefore, you don't need a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Just a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` or even a tuple, `(string key, string value)` would suffice.

Secondly, your `switch` or `if/else` approach is far too procedural for this task. It's a declarative problem, so use a declarative solution:

```
public class ObjectInfo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public (string key,string value) Prop {get;set;}
}

…

private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> ObjectPropMappings =
    new Dictionary<string, string> {
        ["text"] = "UsedInSearch",
        ["number"] = "Decimal",
        ...
    };

...

var resultItems = GetBusinessObjects().Select(businessObject => new ObjectInfo
{
    Prop = (businessObject.Type, businessObject[ObjectPropMappings[businessObject.Type]]),
    Name = businessObject["Name"]
}.ToList();
```

If my assumption that there is only one prop per business object type if false, then re-introduced that Dictionary into `ObjectInfo` and make `ObjectPropMappings` a `Dctionary<string, List<string>>` to handle multiple props.